# SwfitUI @FetchedResults one-many relationship didn't update properly

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I am using SwiftUI with Coredata to display a one to many relationship data elements.

Example:

One `Group` has many `Book`.

I have two views, `GroupView` has many `GroupRowView`s.

```
struct GroupView: View {

    var groups: FetchedResults<Group>

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 32, content: {

                ForEach(contractGroups) { group in
                    HStack {
                        GroupRowView(group: group)
                        Text(String(group.books?.count ?? 0)) // display correct
                                            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                    }

                }

            })
        }
    }
}
```

and the **GroupRowView** is here:

```
struct GroupRowView: View {

    var group: Group

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {

            Color(.white)
            VStack {
                Text(group.name!)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .font(.system(size: 17, weight: .bold, design: .default))

                Text(String(group.books?.count ?? 0)) //display wrong
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            }
        }.frame(width: 120, height: 100, alignment: .center)
    }
}
```

Every time when the `books` was updated, then the book count display correctly in the `GroupView` but not in the `GroupRowView`.

The `group` in `forEach` is `FetchedResults<ContractGroup>.Element`, is it the reason not the same as `var group: ContractGroup` in `GroupRowView`?

How to make the `group.books` in the `GroupRowView` get the changes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to observe `group` in row explicitly, like

```
struct GroupRowView: View {

    @ObservedObject var group: Group

    // ... other code
```